# Find the position of a string match

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a column in Postgres like:

```
name
abc def ghi
lmnop qrst uvw
xyz
```

Is there any way I get the match and the position of the match?
For example
If I search for 'ef' then I should get the first by using a query like:

```
select * from table where name like '%ef%';
```

and the position of the match should be 5.
How can I find the position of the match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact syntax for the Postgres `position()` function is, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

> `position ( substring text IN string text ) → integer`

With the `IN` keyword.

To get **index support**, I suggest:

```sql
SELECT *, position('ef' IN name)
FROM   tbl
WHERE  name ~ 'ef';
```

`name ~ 'ef'` od `name LIKE '%ef%'` can use a trigram index on `(name)`, unlike the expression `position('ef' IN name) > 0`, which is not "sargable". *Big* difference in performance for big tables.

About that trigram index:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Answer (score -1):

```
select name, position('ef', name)
from your_table
where position('ef', name) > 0
```